# onClick on <li> does't trigger

Tags: reactjs, onclick, html-lists

I'm having a headache trying to understand why my onClick on a `<li>` doesn't trigger 
I'm using react 
I'm posting here the snippet of code: 
This is the list creation:

```
                <div className="countryList">
                    <ul>
                        {_adminCodes.map((item) => (
                            <li
                                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                                onClick={handleListCountryClick}
                                className="countryLi">{item.name}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And this is the function `handleListCountryClick`: 
`const handleListCountryClick = () => {console.log("I'm a country!")}`

Any advice would be appreciated! 

EDIT:

  I've tryied:
- onClick={handleListCountryClick()}
- onClick={() => handleListCountryClick()}

EDIT 2: This component (map) is included in a father component (graphs), if I try to trigger the `onClick` in the map component it runs the function, instead if I try to trigger the `onClick` in the father component (graphs) it doesn't work

Here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-negksn?file=src/map.jsx)

Comment: typo - `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

You can try by updating your code to "onClick={() => handleListCountryClick}"

Edit:

This is what I have tried in codeSandbox and getting below results:

```
 class Country extends React.Component {
 render() {
 const adminCodes = ["India", "USA", "UK", "UAE"];

 return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {adminCodes.map((item) => (
        <li
          key={item}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => handleListCountryClick(item)}
        >
          {item}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

 const handleListCountryClick = (item) => {
       console.log(`I'm a ${item}!`);
};

export default Country;
```

Results (on click of listitems in same order):
I'm a India!
I'm a USA!
I'm a UK!
I'm a UAE!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found that the problem isn't in the map component, if i run only the map component runs fine but whenever i try to run it inside the father component (graphs) the console.log (and I assume also the function) doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function with (), by using handleListCountryClick your are referencing the function instead of executing it.

```
onClick={() => {handleListCountryClick()}}
```

Dang ok are you using a class component then try:

```
onClick={() => {this.handleListCountryClick()}}
```

Sorry I tried I would need to see more code to help further.

Test this:

```
onClick={() => {console.log('I worked!!')}}
```

if that works then there is a reference error to the function.

Comment: With the `this.handleListCountryClick()` gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleListCountryClick' of undefined`

Comment: Don't worry, maybe if you specify what do you need I can provide it, I wrote the question with only the list construction and the function for decluttering

Comment: Does the function live in the same component? Is the component class or functional? Where is the function at inside the component?

Comment: The function live in the same component, is functional, and is located before the useEffect

Comment: `onClick={() => {console.log('I worked!!')}}` This also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

usually the `onClick` is written `onClick={() => onClickFunction()}` SO the fact you tried these solutions makes me think there's a problem somewhere else. Can you please edit the question and write more of the component code so we can understand better? Thank You.

Comment: I've included the StackBlitz of the component